# Upload HD content to YouTube

Tags: youtube

I want to upload a number of videos as HD to YouTube, how do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Just upload them as usual, as long as the source material is in HD this is how it will be added to YouTube;

http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=132460

> YouTube offers the option to view content in high definition with 1080p resolution — when the source upload supports it.

Also see;

> **How do you Upload Video in HD to Youtube?**
>
> For the highest quality, YouTube now recommends the following setting for your video:
>   MPEG4 (DivX, Xvid, H.264) format
>
> 1280×720 resolution or 1080p
>
> 128k Mono or 320k Stereo MP3/AAC audio
>
> 24,25 or 30 frames per second
>
> Up to 2GB file size and 15:59 min. duration
>
> YouTube accepts a wide range of video file formats such as .WMV, .AVI and .MOV but you may get the best results from converting your file to MPEG4 video with MP3 audio.

http://www.reelseo.com/youtube-hd-update/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Visit [m.youtube.com](http://m.youtube.com) to get your unique upload email address

I attach them in Gmail and send via [mobile upload email](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=70029) address that YouTube create for me.

of course that videos cropped by me and less that 25 MB. and i believe shorten videos have more usability.

this is an easiest way that i know